# Android device shows warning for my app's performance

Tags: android

I have an app on google play. One of my users send me a feedback, the screenshot below.

[image]

It is actually Turkish and it says ***"This app causes your device to run slowly. Disable the app's autostart feature for better performance."***

I could not understand what is wrong about my app. There is no feature that make the app autostart or any other background services.

Is there any idea about that?
Thanks.

Comment: "I could not understand what is wrong about my app" - neither do we, because we have no information. Maybe you can tell a bit about what your app is for and how it is technically working

Comment: It is an e-commerce app. What is app's autostart feature?

Comment: Is your app restart frequently? means if android kills the app it will restart automatically? this will happen when the memory becomes low. Some of the app's like Clean-master,DU Speed Booster will report this kind of analytic's such as how frequently your app restarts and how many times it restarted.

Comment: Have you registered any `BroadcastReceiver`?